# PHP While Loops In While Loops not working

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Hi I have had a long search for this but have found no fix.

My code is as follows:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost",".........","...........",".........") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

$ctime = time();


$check = "SELECT * FROM thread WHERE forumid='48' AND visible='1' ORDER BY lastpost DESC LIMIT 1" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

//execute the query. 

$rc = mysqli_query($link, $check);

while($rows = $rc->fetch_assoc()){
    $pid = $rows['firstpostid'];                    



    $query = "SELECT * FROM dropouts WHERE date <= $ctime" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

    //execute the query. 

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 

    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        $date = $row['date'];
        $user = $row['username'];

        $sql = "DELETE FROM dropouts WHERE date = $date" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

        //execute the query. 

        $done = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

            $check1 = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE postid='$pid'" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

            //execute the query. 

            $rc1 = mysqli_query($link, $check1);

            while($row1 = $rc1->fetch_array())
            {
                $text = $row1['pagetext'];
                echo str_replace($user, "", $text);

            }
    }   

}
```

The problem is that when I run it like that I get no out put.

If I run it so that the while loops are not in eachother I get output but the script only does it for one row post/row.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I read that it should work but this just isn't working...

Thanks

Comment: what is the output of $row_cnt? Have you tried echoing it. It can be that the query returns 0 or empty.

Comment: echo and exit in each loop. you cannot debug something like this just by sight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried echoing it. It can be that the query returns 0 or empty!

As a beginner in php, you may stumble into these kinds of issues. The best way to understand the problem would be to ECHO & EXIT. Check each step by doing this and you can better understand the problem.

In the problem above, instead of writing the entire code, first of all try checking the small portion of codes and remember:

The best compiler/interpreter lies between you two ears!!